# What is the Empyreal Lord ability Seed of Life?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, powers

All the [Empyreal Lords](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/empyreal-lord/) have a Special Quality called Seed of Life. However, their statblocks don't expand on what this ability does or how any of them got it.

What does this ability do and why do they all have it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seed of Life is listed as part of the [Empyreal Lord traits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#TOC-Empyreal-Lord-Traits-Ex-Sp-or-Su-). A Universal Monster Rule introduced in Bestiary 4. From the SRD:

> Seed of Life (Sp) An empyreal lord can touch a willing creature and imbue it with magical healing power. The target radiates an aura of good as if it were an outsider and gains a +2 insight bonus on all saving throws against negative energy and death effects. As a standard action, the target can release this energy, turning it inward as a heal spell upon itself or outward as a mass cure serious wounds spell on allies within 30 feet (caster level 15th). If not released, the energy dissipates harmlessly after 24 hours. The empyreal lord can use this ability 5 times per day, but only on other creatures.

All Empyreal Lords have the Empyreal Lord Traits, despite none of their statblocks expressly mentioning it. (Similar to Great Old Ones, Demon Lords or other pseudo-subtypes with unique Traits.)